# how to ensure that the editing (IsEdited or whatever) state of an EFCore entity is notified

Tags: c#, wpf, ef-core-2.0

I've got a class Invoice that has InvoiceRows.

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime InvoiceDate {
        get => invoiceDate;
        set => PropertySet<DateTime>(value, ref invoiceDate);
    }
    private DateTime invoiceDate;

    public List<InvoiceRow> Rows { get; } = new List<InvoiceRow>();

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsEdited { get; set; } = false;

    public void PropertySet<T>(T value, ref T field)
    {
        if (value.Equals(field)) return;
        field = value;
        IsEdited = true;
    }

}
```

The Invoice is edited in a WPF graphical interface that need notifications when the invoice has been edited in order to activate the save button, for example.
(In a first implementation i thought that IsEdited was a viewmodel thing and I omitted it from the model and included in the viewmodel instead. Turns out to be quite complex when handling sub-records. However I've not yet fully realized which option the model or the viewmodel implementation is best, and this is possibly a second question.)

The IsEdited is easily managed at record level, but how to handle it at the InvoiceRow level?
The first idea that comes to mind is to notify back to the main record.
This in turn requires additional code to wire up notifications between Invoice and Rows.

Another idea is to leverage the DbContext state that holds in one place the required information instead of gathering it around sub-records.

Are there any other options left? One of the challages of such decision is to fully evaluate the consequences of each approach before hand.  What are the pros/cons of different ways of handling this? 
In my little experience of WPF I've read something about hirearchical viewmodels. Maybe they are suitable for this, handling the wrap-up at the viewmodel level?

Comment: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged event.

Comment: *Are there any other options left?* Not really. Handle the `PropertyChanged` or similar of all `InvoiceRow` objects and set the `IsEdited` property accordingly. This basically turns `Invoice` into a bindable view model that the view should bind to.

Comment: It's often a bad idea to directly expose model objects to a view. You're usually better off working with viewmodels that implement inotifypropertychanged.  Generally speaking. Unless this is a trivial app. don't retain an instance of a dbcontext across your application and don't use EF change tracking. Copy properties betwen EF model objects and viewmodels. Make viewmodel self tracking.